# Drupal 7: Local site URLs all point to production site

Tags: 7, configuration, uri

I've been trying to figure this out for a while on this one particularly large site.

Every single URL on every page and menu, even the admin menu as the wrong url. I've tried this with WAMP, MAMP, Vagrant, Docker and Docksal with the same results.

A better explanation: 
I'd expect all urls to be what I've setup on my local machine as the base. Like mysite.loc, or for docksal, mysite.docksal.

But when I pull the repo for this site and set it up, then load it...all urls are the production urls. Anything I click on goes to production. All submit buttons goto production. Almost like they are saved in the DB, but the definitely aren't.

I've tried setting the base URL. That doesn't work.

I've turned off all the modules, both contrib and core. That doesn't work.

I've changed themes. That doesn't work.

It's something within the filesystem of this site but I'm not sure where to look at this point. Probably a hack someone put in somewhere.

Any thoughts of where to look?

Comment: What steps did you take to set up the website from production to local? This shouldn't have to do with your stack, themes and modules. Focus on your installation. .htaccess, settings.php, etc. Also, are you using drush? In my local version of production, I didn't have to set a base URL. Maybe you need to comment out the base URL.

Comment: This is also worth mentioning, but did someone build the menu using full URLs?

Comment: Can you try doing a directory search on your project with the production URL or part of production URL first?

Comment: @Christia Those are good guesses, but putting full URLs in the main menu wouldn't explain all system and admin menu URLs and tabs all pointing to the production site. 

Steps I took were I pushed all production files to a git repo. Setup my local environment, pulled all the files, pulled the database from production to local. Totally different htaccess and settings.php right now since I'm using docksal. I am using drush via docksal. I have never set the base URL before, but I thought I would mention that because other post mentioned to try it.

Comment: @KiranD Tried it. No luck. There isn't anything in the filesystem that has hard coded production URLs. Maybe something in the DB? I'm not even sure where to look there though because it's got a ton of tables and custom fields. Maybe in the variable table?

Comment: What does `admin/config/system/site-information` give as the prefix for your default home page? Turn off "clean URLs" and then turn them back on after you clear all caches. Also do a MySQL query of `filepath` field in `files` table and see what that says. Also check the cookie domain in settings.php.

Comment: Prefix is the production url, which is weird.

I'm pretty sure the issue is somewhere in the DB. I just dropped it and rant the install to create all the tables and had no issues once it was done. Let give your other suggestions a try.

Comment: I don't seem to have a 'files' table in my DB. Turning off clean URLs, clearing cache, and turning them back on didn't work.

What's really annoying is that even when I click a system submit button, they all redirect to the production website. So I literally can't navigate or click on anything without being redirected.

Comment: So this is interesting. The DB is huge, but I spent a lot of time just going table by table and looking through rows. I found an old table left by the "Domain" module that we no longer use. It was for language switching. It still had the domain for the English in the table and the Spanish side. I changed the English domain to the local URL and that actually changed the prefix in admin/config/system/site-information to be the correct local URL, however, it did not fix my issue with all URLs still pointing to the production site.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

If you're using the module "Domain Access", the uninstall hooks do not work properly (or at least they didn't on our site).

You'll need to go into your DB and change the domain settings after you've disabled your module.

All of the Domain module tables that have your production (or old URL) in them need to be changed. Removing those tables will likely corrupt your DB and make the site unusable.

Comment: Agreed. "Domain Access" module is tricky when you switch the site between environments.